# repository.findAll() method returns nothing in spring-data

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to get all relationships using spring-data and neo4j.

My Repository

```
public interface RelationshipNeo4JRepository extends
    GraphRepository<Relationship> {
}
```

Relationship Class:

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class Relationship {

   @GraphId
   Long nodeId;
   @StartNode
   private Node startNode;
   @EndNode
   private Node endNode;
   @Indexed
   @RelationshipType
   private String type;
   //getter setter
```

}

When I am trying to use findAll() method, I am not getting any relationships. but I am getting total using count(). 
Please help me using cypher query or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you should use an SDN repository for.

Just go to the Neo4j API and call:

```
GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllRelationships();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using @Query on method in repository.

```
@Query(value="start r=rel(*) return r);
public List<Relationship> getAll();
```